# Google Adwords and MCC account issue

Tags: google, google-ads

I have a Google account for ages and I used it for Adwords. But Now I have to logout and log back in with a different account for another Adwords campaign group

so my personal account has a canceled Adwords account. I tried to link my personal Google account to the active Adwords account, but that is not allowed because my personal account is still linked to an (inactive) Adwords account.

Now I have searched the newsgroups from Google for this and found a solution. Go to Google account settings, products and hit 'edit' but there is no option to permanently delete the inactive Adwords account.

All other solutions include a new Google account, but I use the Google account for to much to give up.

please forgive me if this is not the correct SE website to ask.

Comment: Yes, I had a similar annoying problem when Google decided to split my accounts up and moved everything from my Google Apps email to a gmail login I never used. I didn't find a solution then, but I'll check it again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure in AdWords you can have multiple emails associated with one account (so two people can work on the same AdWords account each using their own Google Account). Have you tried creating a "dummy" Google Account associating that with your inactive AdWords account, make it the primary account holder and delete the other - essentially your not unlinking the account but instead transferring it.

Comment: it says that my google account already has an adwords account and therefor cannot be added as secondary account

Comment: Right I'm saying create a new Google account which you have no plans to use and add that as your secondary account to the inactive AdWords account, once that is added you should be able to switch it from secondary to primary, freeing up your main Google account to be unlinked (as it will now be the secondary account).

Comment: Ok! will try that. thanks for your comment. it makes it clearer for me. will let you know if it worked out

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know of any way at the moment to "unlink" the inactive account.

Alternatively you could use this Chrome extension to at least ease your changing of accounts:
http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/google-account-switcher/

Comment: there were sources online to unlink your account, but that option seems to be disappeared. Firefox is my main browser. will try to find a firefox extension and hope that it is a good workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

To unlink the account you need to change your main Google Account email address. The MCC/Adwords account issue is a pain, so be mindful of the email you plan to use for an Adwords account and the MCC account.